What does the Grothendieck group of $(\Bbb{N}, x\oplus y := 6xy + x + y)$ look like?
Let $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ and define $\oplus : \Bbb{N}^2 \to \Bbb{N}$ to be $x\oplus y := 6xy + x + y$.
It is cancellative (associative / monoid law) since if $x\oplus y = 6xy + x + y = 6xz + x + z = x\oplus z \implies 6(x(y - z)) + y - z = (6x + 1)(y-z) = 0$ and $6x + 1 \neq 0$ or else $6 \mid 1$ which is absurd.  And therefore $y = z$.
Therefore the Grothendieck group $Z$ of $N = (\Bbb{N}, \oplus)$ exists, is non-trivial and in fact embeds a copy of $N$ inside of it.
Therefore, we may work merely with $x \equiv (x,0) \in Z$ by a similar construction to this: Grothendieck group of the integers.
However, was wondering if we can work with the Grothendieck group in the usual algebra-like way, i.e. when we work in the rationals we work with fractions which are very familiar.  So is there some more familiar way of working in this Grothendieck group?

You're simply transporting the multiplicative structure of $\Bbb N$ along the bijection $,n\mapsto 6n+1.\ $ We can transport it along a bijection to any set of the same cardinality.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but note that
$$6xy + x + y = \frac{1}{6} ((6x+1)(6y+1) - 1).$$
So if you do a change of variable $x' = 6x + 1$ and $y' = 6y + 1$, we have
$$\frac{x' - 1}{6} \oplus \frac{y'-1}{6} = x \oplus y = 6xy + x + y = \frac{x'y' - 1}{6}.$$
So the situation is isomorphic the monoid $6\mathbb{N} + 1$ under usual multiplication, with identity 1. The Grothendieck group just consists of $\frac{x}{x'}$ for $x,x' \in 6\mathbb{N} + 1$.

I already know this.  $f: (\Bbb{N}, \oplus) \to (\Bbb{N}, \cdot)$ is an injective monoid homomorphism.  Where $f(n) = 6n + 1$

Cool, do you consider the group $(6\mathbb{N} + 1) \cup (6\mathbb{N} + 1)^{-1}$ under multiplication not familiar enough?

that is right.  You're right!  I'm just wondering how I work in $6\Bbb{N} + 5$ since together $6\Bbb{N} + {1, 5}$ another cancellative monoid is formed.

Same argument lead you to consider $(6\mathbb{N} + 1) \cup (6\mathbb{N} + 5) \cup (6\mathbb{N} + 1)^{-1} \cup (6\mathbb{N} + 5)^{-1}$ under multiplication.

@dummy why union?

@MartinBrandenburg it can actually be upgraded to disjoint union.  Or almost disjoint.  Sometimes ${1}$.

No I mean you should talk about fractions $x/y$, but not only about $x$ and $1/y$.

Oops you are correct.

@MartinBrandenburg Oh I guess he's saying take those sets as free monoid generators

All you have to write is $\Bbb{Q}{\gt 0} \cap \langle 6\Bbb{Z} \pm 1\rangle{\Bbb{Q}}^{\times}$.

I fixed the answer accordingly.

@DanielDonnelly Isn't everything in this answer already in your question? What here is new to you?
